# The 80/20 rule, Open XML charts

Tags: line, mschart, openxml-sdk, linechart

My client has asked for a powerpoint chart of the type LineChart showing the 80/20 rule.

Which means that in every market, there should be only few number of brands that control about 80 % of the market. What he basically wants is a line indicating when the graph line has hit 80 % (the red line in the image below).

I have no problem drawing the below graph, using open xml (let me know if someone needs my help in this issue), my problem is drawing the red line above the chart.

[image: Graph showing the 80/20 rule]

The above image is sent by my client.

I'm really out of thought regarding this issue so I'm looking for ideas on how to tackle this problem.

I'm using Open XML SDK 2.0  to generate the chart from .net.

Comment: are you asking how you would **overlay** a line like that at the right spot? Basically, you have an even number of points on your chart, so what you'll need to do is pre-calculate where you want your 80% by choosing the right point on the graph? How do do that? measure the distance between points, the height/width of the chart and any margins and sum/divide to get the right location.